# Bathymetry Interpolation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation, bathymetry

I'm trying to create an interpolation of xyz data in QGIS. The data has successfully interpolated, but there is some strange striping or banding on the final result that I cannot seem to get rid of. See the images [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05ZYl.jpg)

The first (black and white) was created by saving the data points as a shapefile, then interpolating. Parameters in TIN interpolation were cubic method, with x and y set to 5 meters. I let col and row define themselves- how would that affect the result?

The second was with the xyz data loaded as a deliminated text layer. Interpolated the same as above.

The methods with the basic interpolation package do not change the result. Banding appeared with both linear and cubic options. I also looked at contours which exhibit the same problem (see the third image). Data itself is fine.

The banding might have a geographic cause- it is occuring over an area deeper than the surroundings. However, I do not expect it to create this level of an issue.

Comment: That looks like triangulation due to low density or gaps in your point data. What does your point data look like on top of it?

Comment: Michael- I've got good data coverage. See this image: http://imgur.com/vo7Cb2x with older depth data from another source layered on top. Plenty of data points covering the space.

Comment: That is odd. The image in your link shows a regular spacing of points which suggests to me that it was created from an interpolation, do you have the raw soundings? At this point I would contact the company that performed the soundings and ask *what's up with this data?* Perhaps they did not account for the rise and fall of the sounding vessel and the data was broken before you got it.